# Image with a hole through two backgrounds

Tags: html, css

On the link there is an example; I have three elements, in this case, the body with the a universe background, the div, with a white background and an img where in the middle there is a hole. I want to see the first UNIVERSE background inside the heart shape and not the second/WHITE.

https://jsfiddle.net/adrianvcch/t053p4hb/

```css
html {
  background-color: black;
}
body {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
}
.heart {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
  <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/cqraf51bn/heart.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Huh?  So what color should the heart be?

Comment: add `background-color: black;` to the `.heart`?

Comment: I want to see the first background through the heart

Comment: There's no way to tell the middle layer to have a partially transparent background so you'll have to detect the bottom background color that you want to 'show through" and imitate it inside the heart.

Comment: @jdm2112 thats good but in my case is not a plain colour, its an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

***USING AN IMAGE:***

Since the real case needs to use an image here's what can be done:

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
}
html,
.heart {
  background-color: black;
}
.heart {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
  <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/cqraf51bn/heart.png" />
</div>
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

***USING A CSS SHAPE:***

Here's something you could try:

1. Use a heart shape with plain CSS.
2. Set the same background-color in your html and heart with multiple selectors separated by comma using the same css property.

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
}
.heart {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}
.heart:before {
  left: 0;
  top: -30px;
}
.heart:after {
  left: 30px;
  top: 0;
}
html,
.heart,
.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  background-color: black;
}
.heart-wrapper {
  background-color: #c95253;
  padding: 105px 80px 35px 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart-wrapper">
  <div class="heart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great and I thats what I asked for, and for that reason I accepted the answer but unfortunately the real case that I am working on, the heart is actually a text image, and I am not going to repruduce the words in pure css

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my answer and hope this other solution is what best suits your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

**CSS Masking**

Mask @ [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask)

```css
html {
  background-image: url(http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/files/2013/02/2xcluster.jpg);
}
body {
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.heart {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-mask: url(http://s3.postimg.org/cqraf51bn/heart.png);
  mask: url(http://s3.postimg.org/cqraf51bn/heart.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
  <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/cqraf51bn/heart.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: But where is the second layer, the white one?

Comment: @AdriánVázquez you're not making much sense, you want the heart to be filled black?

Comment: I thought I was clear enough. Inside the heart, now is white because its is the second layer, I want to see the first background that is from body, which in this case is an image.

Comment: You can see through the image can't you? The div still has a white background, you just can't see it. Note...suppport is poor for this so your browser may not show it, Otherwise you are basically out of luck.

Comment: This is good @Paulie_D , but I think it's not what the user is asking, what I understood he wants is the body to have background-color: white and make the heart have the same background-color as the html without filling the heart manually which is probably not possible without JS.

Comment: This is what I see in Chrome: https://s31.postimg.org/b5eettcxn/chrome.png
This is what I see in Firefox:
https://s31.postimg.org/lti5snmwr/firefox.png

Comment: As I said, support is poor....but there is no other CSS method. Perhaps you need to re-consider what it is you are trying to do..or the way you are going about it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this changes into your codes, But your image should be transparent to adapt the `background color`.

```
html {
   background:url(https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature);
 }

body {

  margin: 50px;
  height: 500px;
}

.heart {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
img{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, black is just an example, I want to see the first background.

Comment: Tell me background-color, you can even change that to any color like #f22.

Comment: Sorry, did you check the fiddle? The HTML has an image as a background. I want to see inside the heart, this first image/background

Comment: Remove background -color from your body.

Comment: @AdriánVázquez Is there a color name for your first background, there are only three points are assigned in your code heart image with white and black background.